# days hours minutes d hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, time, duration

I need to convert:

- 12 Days 2 Hours 43 Minutes
- 3 Hours 18 Minutes
- 1 Day 1 Minute

Into:

```
hh:mm
```

Is there a way to use just a simple formula for all cases? Thank you!

Cheers!

Medicloreans

Comment: in which program? or language

Comment: in what format do you have the input values? Are they text? Date/number?

Comment: is the data that needs to be converted literal in the exact format as you posted? If so, do you want the results (in your example) to be `107:20`, `3:18`, and `72:1`, respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function NewTime(SIn As String) As String
   Dim nMinutes As Long, nHours As Long, V As Long
   Dim Tag As String
   ary = Split(SIn, " ")

   For i = 0 To UBound(ary) - 1 Step 2
      V = ary(i)
      Tag = Replace(ary(i + 1), "s", "")
      If Tag = "Day" Then nHours = nHours + 24 * V
      If Tag = "Hour" Then nHours = nHours + V
      If Tag = "Minute" Then nMinutes = nMinutes + V
   Next i
   NewTime = nHours & ":" & nMinutes
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**